# How do I convert a relative PIDL into an absolute PIDL?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I want to use `SHGetFileInfo`  to get windows control panel icon,I use Shell to get windows control panel 
Code:

```
var
  psfDeskTop: IShellFolder;
  psfWork: IShellFolder;

  pidworkDir: PITEMIDLIST;
  pidChild: PITEMIDLIST;

  pEnumList: IEnumIDList;
  celtFetched: ULONG;
  //chEaten, dwAttributes: ULONG;
  FileInfo: SHFILEINFOW;

  //conGUID: string;
  StrRetName: TStrRet;
  Name: PChar;

begin

  SHGetDesktopFolder(psfDeskTop);
  SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, CSIDL_CONTROLS, pidworkDir);
  psfDeskTop.BindToObject(pidworkDir, nil, IID_IShellFolder, psfWork);
  psfWork.EnumObjects(0, SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS or SHCONTF_FOLDERS or SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN, pEnumList);

  while pEnumList.Next(1, pidChild, celtFetched) = 0 do
  begin

    //here I want to use SHGetFileInfo to get file icon
    //but , SHGetFileInfo need a absolute PIDL,IEnumIDList enumerates relative PIDL

  end  

end;
```

I found a function called [ILCombine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN to do that , but I can't found in Delphi , I wonder if possible to combine pidworkDir and pidChild to get a absolute PIDL in Delphi?

Or is there any other way to get a file's icon?

Comment: You don't really need to get an absolute PIDL. Call `psfWork.GetUIObjectOf(..., IExtractIcon, ...)` on the relative PIDL to get an icon extractor for the given file. Use that to get the icon instead of `ShGetFileInfo`.

Comment: I'm working for JAM Software and we have developed a product called ShellBrowser. It's available in Delphi and .Net versions and contains all the stuff concerning the Windows Shell API you may possibly need, e.g. in your case for querying Icons or thumbnails for certain items.
We aim to provide as much of the functionality of the Windows Explorer as possible.

There are free fully functional trial versions (just a nag screen outside the IDE) that you can download at our website. I can give you a link if you're interested in learning more about ShellBrowser but you will easily find us on Google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed call [`ILCombine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776437.aspx) from Delphi. You need to use the `ShlObj` unit.

```
uses
  ShlObj;
....
pidItemAbsolute = ILCombine(pidworkDir, pidChild);
```

If your Delphi doesn't have `ILCombine` declared then you can import it like this:

```
function ILCombine(pidl1, pidl2: PItemIDList): PItemIDList; 
    stdcall; external 'shell32.dll';
```

Comment: I use the ShlObj unit , but there no ILCombine function , is because I use Delphi 2009 ?

Comment: Probably. I'll update the answer in a minute to help you solve that.