# Windows Shell: How do you determine if a PIDL is absolute or relative and how do you convert relative to absolute?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

Given a PIDL, how do you determine if it's absolute or relative?

Having a known relative PIDL, how do you convert it to absolute?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess the question is, where is this PIDL coming from? If it's from your own code, you should already know. If it's from the OS, then it's documented what type it is.

Comment: A PIDL is just a list of IDs, there's no way to know if it's absolute or relative. If it's relative, it's relative to the shell folder that gave birth to it., so to convert it to absolute, you can concatenate with this shell folder's absolute PIDL.

Comment: Refer: [How do I convert a relative PIDL into an absolute PIDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157412/how-do-i-convert-a-relative-pidl-into-an-absolute-pidl) , [ILCombine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-ilcombine) is what you need.