# How to extract the folder path from PItemIDList parameter in TRzShellTree.OnAddItem event handler?

Tags: shell, delphi, winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I have a `TRzShellTree` control (by Ray Konopka from the Konopka Signature VCL Controls 7.0 available in GetIt):

```
object RzShellTree1: TRzShellTree
  Left = 0
  Top = 41
  Width = 201
  Height = 428
  Align = alLeft
  BaseFolder.Pidl = {
    004301000014001F50E04FD020EA3A6910A2D808002B30309D19002F433A5C00
    00000000000000000000000000000000000054003100000000003D5465581100
    44454C50484900003E0009000400EFBE1423F90E42549B502E00000000930F00
    000001000000000000000000000000000000DFED4800440045004C0050004800
    4900000016005A0031000000000042546956100053757065724D525500004200
    09000400EFBE2154F655425469562E000000210A000000004B00000000000000
    0000000000000000C43CDA00530075007000650072004D005200550000001800
    660031000000000042546F56100050524F4A45437E3100004E0009000400EFBE
    4254695642546F562E00000043EB0A0000000B00000000000000000000000000
    000008E22E00500052004F004A004500430054002000470052004F0055005000
    5300000018000000}
  Indent = 19
  ReadOnly = True
  SelectionPen.Color = clBtnShadow
  TabOrder = 0
  OnChange = RzShellTree1Change
  OnDragOver = RzShellTree1DragOver
end
```

...where in the `TRzShellTree.OnAddItem` event handler I need to get the PATH of each added folder:

```
procedure TformMain.RzShellTreeGroupsAddItem(Sender: TObject; ParentIShf: IShellFolder_NRC; ParentAbsIdList, ItemRelIdList: PItemIDList; Attribs: Integer; var AllowAdd: LongBool);
begin
  // How to get the PATH of the added folder?
end;
```

I assume this could be done by extracting the path from the `ItemRelIdList: PItemIDList` parameter. But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RzShellUtils unit contains a number of helpful functions to deal with this sort of thing. In particular,

```
uses
  RzShellUtils;

procedure TForm13.RzShellTree1AddItem(Sender: TObject; ParentIShf: IShellFolder_NRC; ParentAbsIdList,
  ItemRelIdList: PItemIDList; Attribs: Integer; var AllowAdd: LongBool);
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := ShellGetPathFromIdList( ItemRelIdList );
  CodeSite.Send( 'S', S );
end;
```

Comment: Two other questions: 1. How to set the `RzShellTree1.BaseFolder` to a custom path (e.g. C:\MyCustomDirectory) programmatically at run-time? 2. In the `RzShellTree1AddItem` event-handler, how to change the node-text programmatically at run-time? (There seems to be no way to get the node in `RzShellTree1AddItem`).

Comment: Doesn't `ShellGetPathFromIdList()` need an absolute PIDL? What good is a path of a relative PIDL without knowing which absolute PIDL it is relative to?

Comment: `RzShellUtils` also has `ShellGetFriendlyNameFromIdList()` which takes `ParentIShf` into account when getting the path for `ItemRelIdList`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the full path, then combine the `ParentAbsIdList` and `ItemRelIdList` lists into a new absolute `PItemIDList` list:

[How do I convert a relative PIDL into an absolute PIDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157412/)

And then use [`SHGetPathFromIDList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetpathfromidlistw).

Alternatively, you can use [`ParentIShf.GetDisplayNameOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-getdisplaynameof) instead, passing it `ItemRelIdList` as-is. If you specify only the `SHGDN_FORPARSING` flag, you will get back the child's full path. If you include the `SHGDN_INFOLDER` flag, you will get back the child's path relative to its parent.

The `RzShellUtils` unit provides utility functions for working with `PItemIDList`s. For instance,
`ConcatIdLists()` (and `ShellMemFree()`), `ShellGetPathFromIdList()`, and `ShellGetFriendlyNameFromIdList()`:

```
Path := ShellGetFriendlyNameFromIdList(ParentIShf, ItemRelIdList, fnForParsing);
```

Comment: This seems to work: https://www.screencast.com/t/ZgSmLMzClwY Is this correct?

Comment: @user1580348 You are close. You are leaking the `PItemIDList` that `ILCombine()` returns, you need to call `ILFree()` (or `CoTaskMemFree()`) when you are done using it. Also, `SHGetPathFromIDList()` requires a `Char[]` array that is at least `MAX_PATH` (260) characters.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer AS WELL. Is this possible? How can I do that?

Comment: @user1580348 only one answer can be marked as accepted. Choose whichever one helped you more. You can upvote the other one.